# Save click-amounts within a text-file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I am working on a sort of voting-thing for my wordpress-project; where users shall be able to click on a `li`-element and the results of these clicks (comparable to likes) gets displayed directly. That's - due to support form the community - already working with that code:

```
$('#result li').click(function(){
  this.clicked = this.clicked ? this.clicked + 1 : 1;
  $(this).html(this.clicked);
});
```

As this is only saving the interactions for the time of the visit, I'd like to save and retrieve all user-likes within a txt-file (I guess that's the easiest way to do it)

I am especially wondering, how I could identify the element that triggered click-amount a, if there is no identifier besides "this" to it?

Comment: no, txt file is not the easiest way. you're using wordpress, that means you've got a database. use that instead. As for identifying the click, the click() handler gets passed an event object that contains details about WHICH object was clicked. e.g. `.click(function(e) { console.log(e.target); })`

Comment: Saving things to text files in web applications will result in access sharing violations (which will result in missing data) because more than one person can be accessing it at the same time. Its better to use a database.

Answer (score 1):

If you want record yours user interaction, the best way would be to save the clicks as rows in a table. As Marc B said, you already have a Datebase, so you should create a table in it with the columns you need (For example user_id, link_pressed, etc). After this, you should create a little PHP or ASP or whatever server-side language you prefer script that introduces this registries into your table. Your javascript should call this script through AJAX. This way you can record the users click. However take into account this is not safe because anyone could call your script and introduce fake interactions. You must implement some basic server-side validation. For example, check there is only one row per user and no more, etc.